# Returning a 3rd column value based on two columns matching

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a sheet that will allow the selection of city-pairs and travel class that will then return the amount of airline miles earned.

```
CITY_A   CITY_B   CLASS   MILES
SFO      JFK      ECON    3000
JFK      LHR      ECON    3300
```

My plan is to have a separate sheet with all the valid city-pairs and related data, and using the data validation tool I'd present drop-down choices in the active sheet rows.

I'm just unsure exactly where to start - VLOOKUP and FILTER formulas both seem to be relevant.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realise my title is a bit wrong, it should be return a 4th col value based on 3 columns matching - but I hope the concept is the same regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index-match with more then one criteria:
https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/
Or here:
http://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/
Warning: could be quite slow to my liking for 300 or so rows.